# How to handle rarely used keyboard layouts in gnome?

Tags: linux, unix, gnome, keyboard-layout

I use 2 keyboard layouts regularly, and another 1 a bit more rarely. It would be really nice if I could set the switch-layout key combination to alter only between the 2 I use often, and have another way to switch to the 3rd.

Is that possible? Any other solutions except enabling the 3rd layout only when I need it?

Comment: This should belong to [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Set a different mapping for the keys you use for switching in the 3rd layout.
For example, if M-Caps Lock changes the keyboard layout, set Meta to another key in the 3rd layout.

This page should help:
http://hektor.umcs.lublin.pl/~mikosmul/computing/articles/custom-keyboard-layouts-xkb.html